# Eiffel EWF Application standalone C Bind Error

Tags: eiffel

After starting it with <kbd>F5</kbd>, it seems that when I stop an EWF application (from estudio stop button) it takes up to 10 seconds to free the defined port on linux debian machine, Don't know if its only on this OS but **is there a way to make it stop quicker**? I always have to wait for some seconds to start it again after some corrections.
[image]

Comment: This is related to TIME_WAIT on Linux.
this TIME_WAIT exists for security reason, to avoid accepting in a new process for the same port, packets that may be "late".  With a big enough TIME_WAIT, this should not occur.
Reducing this TIME_WAIT may be dangerous.

Of course, during development, this is annoying. We could eventually see if this is possible from the program to change this behavior.
To be continued...

Comment: @Jocelyn thx, but this is an answer for me, not a comment!!

Comment: I don't provide any solution, that's why I posted it as comment.
I guess we could use SO_REUSEADDR but only during development, as I guess this would be a serious security issue.

Comment: @Jocelyn No solution but an explanation which worth being put viewable for most of the people who encounter this issue. Maybe with a link on linux TIME_WAIT documentation. Don't you think? for the visibility of this issue and reasons there is no solution it could be good....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eiffel Web Framework, app run on linux raises \`Address already in use: IO\_FAILURE raised\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53932111/eiffel-web-framework-app-run-on-linux-raises-address-already-in-use-io-failur)

Answer (score 2):

my actual best workaround is:
`sudo sh -c 'echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_recycle'`

see more info on the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53932111/eiffel-web-framework-app-run-on-linux-raises-address-already-in-use-io-failur)...

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the app in workbench mode (F5) or Workbench System (Ctrl + Alt + F5)?
Do you have a minimal example to reproduce the issue?
Is it possible to reproduce the issue with one of the provided EWF examples?

Comment: actually, I tested with an empty project and seems that I messed up somewhere cause its not happening with a new project...

Comment: Tipically a point you could put as a comment on the question instead of answer cause it's not one ;-) Thx for the helping