# Eiffel Web Framework, app run on linux raises `Address already in use: IO_FAILURE raised`

Tags: tcp, eiffel

After stopping an EWF app and starting it again in a Address already in use: `c_bind` `Address already in use: IO_FAILURE raised`

[image]

As explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/17232/47775), it seems that TCP socket timeout is not available for some time before being released by OS.

Answer (score 0):

The best workaround I found is

```
sudo sh -c 'echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_recycle'
```

Credits to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/17232/47775)

> I believe that the idea of the socket being unavailable to a program is to allow any TCP data segments still in transit to arrive, and get discarded by the kernel. That is, it's possible for an application to call close(2) on a socket, but routing delays or mishaps to control packets or what have you can allow the other side of a TCP connection to send data for a while. The application has indicated it no longer wants to deal with TCP data segments, so the kernel should just discard them as they come in.
>
> did change things. The second "opener" only took about 3 seconds to get its new socket.